# Why $\delta$ is choosen between $0$ & $1$ in showing $f(z) =\frac{1}{z}$ is not uniformly continuous in the region $|z|<1$

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, uniform-continuity

In the below attached picture, there is, solution provided for showing

> $f(z) =\frac{1}{z}$ is not uniformly continuous un the region $|z|<1$

[image]

By definition of uniform continuity, we have for given any $\epsilon >0$ there exists $\delta >0$ (depending on $\epsilon$ only not on particular point $z_0$) such that, $|f(z) -f(z_0) |< \epsilon$ whenever $|z-z_0|<\delta$.

**So clearly definition does not say anything about $\delta$. So how can they choose $\delta$ between $0$ & $1$. Why can't be $\delta>1$?**

Since $|z-z_0|$ denotes distance between point $z$ & $z_0$ and as these two points lies in the region $|z|<1$ i.e. set of all points lying inside the circle of radius $1$ with center at origin. hence distance between $z$ and $z_0$ **can** be greater than $1$. So how can they choose $\delta < 1$?

Comment: If the property should hold for all $\vert z-z_0\vert< \delta$ when $\delta>1$, you can know that it holds for all $\vert z-z_0\vert <\theta<1$. You are just looking for a contradiction in an easier to work with subset.

Comment: In the picture it is mentioned that, we should be able to find $\delta$  say between $0$ & $1$ how?

Answer (score 1):

The argument is as I said. If $\vert z-z_0\vert<\delta_\epsilon$ implies $\vert f(z)-f(z_0)\vert<\epsilon$, while $\delta_\epsilon\geq1$, then $\vert z-z_0\vert<\eta_\epsilon$ implies $\vert f(z)-f(z_0)\vert<\epsilon$ for any $0<\eta_\epsilon<1$. Now just work with this $\eta_\epsilon$ instead. They can just always replace $\delta_\epsilon$ with an $0<\eta_\epsilon<1$.

**Later Edit:**

There is indeed a problem at sets whose closure contain $z=0$, for the reason you said. One cannot extend $f$ to $0$ continuously, but $f$ is continuous at any $A\subseteq \mathcal{C}\setminus \{0\}$. Moreover, $f$ is uniformly continuous on such an $A$, if $A$ is compact. Therefore, any counterexamples to uniform continuity will have to come from points close to $z=0$. I hope this what you were asking about in the comment.

Comment: Sir, further as $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ is not defined at $z=0$ hence there is something wrong here? Something wrong with the region?

Comment: @GeneralMathematics I added an edit trying to answer that.